# Include "<?php include('myfile.php')" in an html file with str_replace

Tags: php, tags, str-replace

I have to replace a block of text in around 2 000 files and replace it by an include('myText.php');

The problem here is, it's in a html file. In that case i also need to put the php tags in it 
but i dont find a way to do it.

Here is my code

```
$start = "<is_comment>";
 $end = "</is_comment>";

 $startChain = strpos($fileContent, $start);

 $endChain = strpos($fileContent, $end) + strlen($end);


 $text = substr($fileContent, $startChain, $endChain - $startChain);
 //echo htmlspecialchars($text);

 $content = str_replace($text, "<?php include('showISComment.php?project=$project'); ?>", file_get_contents($file));
```

And in the php file im doing it, when i put the php tags, it doesnt identified it as text, but automatically as tags.

thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the function declared in `showISComment.php` to generate the `replace_text` first and then do: `$content = str_replace($text, $replace_text);`

Comment: Can you give me the example..

Comment: Your question isn't very clear what the problem is. I think it may be that the file is still named `.html`, so it doesn't get put through the PHP processor when you access it. You need to rename it to something.php.

Comment: Also, instead of `str_replace()`, you can use `substr_replace()`.

Comment: @Bamar : I can't rename it.. theres is around 2000 of those files.
The thing i want is to integrate the php tags "<?php ... ?>" in the text replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you an example (as requested), I assume there is a function declared in `showISComment.php` which gets a `string` and returns `"true"` or `"false"`:

```
// showISComment.php
function isComment($project) {
    if (...) {
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

Now in your code, do something like this:

```
require_once("showISComment.php");
// ...
$replace_text = isComment($project);
$content = str_replace($text, $replace_text, file_get_contents($file));
```

Comment: you sir ...are maybe a genius.. lets try that solution